# A list of world projection that make "beautiful" map in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system

I was making a globe world map with the "on the fly" function in the project Properties, which changing all the project CRS simultaneous [image]
The "World_Robinson" projection make a beautiful oval map. I was wondering what other projection can be used for a beautiful 3D map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going through the CRS list and picked up the projections that make a nice 3D globe map. It is important emphasize  that in no way this list is a fall list of the world projection. It is only the projection that I found suitable for making a beautiful 3D map.

CRS :Sphere_Quartic_Authalic
[image]
CRS: Sphere_Eckert_V
[image]
CRS: PTRA08 / LAEA Europe
[image]
CRS: Sphere_Eckert_I
[image]
CRS: Sphere_Loximuthal
[image]
CRS: Sphere_Van_der_Grinten_I
[image]
CRS: World_Robinson
[image]